# Merging similar SQL rows

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, merge

I want to merge rows base of some IF condition in SQL. My database looks like this

```
| com_id | bom_id |fil_title
=====================
| 6067   | 6070   |NULL
| 6067   | 6070   |07
| 6067   | 6071   |NULL
| 6067   | 6071   |07
| 6067   | 6069   |NULL
```

What I want to achieve is

```
| com_id | bom_id |fil_title
=====================
| 6067   | 6070   |07
| 6067   | 6071   |07
| 6067   | 6069   |NULL
```

So every time if i had two rows with same bom_id i want to merge them in one, but if I had one just leave it.

It's just a sample - my full query is bigger, but problem is just there. I know that SQL has some IF but I don't know really how to use it here.

//EDIT
What I didn't mention precisely I have more fields with some random values. I want to pick this values only from row which is not null. (but only if we had 2 rows). That's why distinct and simply agrregate doesn't work

Comment: "That's why [...] simply agrregate doesn't work ": I don't see how Yogesh Sharma's answer doesn't work for you. If there are more columns like `fil_title`, then treat them just the same `select com_id, bom_id, max(fil_title), max(another_column), max(yet_another_column) ...`.

Comment: I cannot take max(another column) because it not necessarly maximum value. Sometimes is max sometimes is min. It can't be clarified. That's why I want to pick value from specific row.

Comment: Which row? So far you have only shown the situation where one row has a value and the other has not. So it doesn't really matter whether to use `MAX` or `MIN` to grab that one value. If it's not about picking the one value from a list of values where all others are NULL, then you are suddenly asking a very different question. You may want to accept the answer here and open a new request with the new question and more thorough sample data including edge cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do *aggregation* :

```
select com_id, bom_id, max(fil_title)
from table t
group by com_id, bom_id;
```

If that example result is from other query then use `subquery` instead :

```
select com_id, bom_id, max(fil_title)
from ( <query here>
     ) t
group by com_id, bom_id;
```

Comment: If I do aggreagation there is something wrong with another field 
Column 'tew_component.com_tag' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Toriam . . . This answers the question that you asked -- your question has no column called `com_tag`.  I would suggest that you accept this answer and ask *another* question.  If you change the question, you'll invalidate the answers that people have given you, which can attract downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use distinct to do so

```
select com_id , bom_id , max(fil_title)
from table t
group by com_id , bom_id
```

Comment: I already use distinct but there are some fields which is diffrent.

Comment: Remove the `DISTINCT` from your query. It's superfluous. You cannot get duplicate rows when what you are grouping by is in your select list. (And `DISTINCT` is not a function. The parentheses are only creating confusion for the (human) reader of your query; they should not be there in the first place.)